# PHP and Javascript - log complete workflow

Tags: php, javascript, debugging, logging

I am working in a complex Webframework with lots of Javascript in the Frontend and lots of PHP in the backend. Since I’m new to it, finding out the workflow is quite a hassle. Is there a way to log the complete sequence of function calls (in PHP, JS or both) from the moment a request is sent until the response is executed (or the JS after the request has been sent is executed?) That would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

There's no perfect solution here but you will probably have to just use browser debugging tools like Firefox's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome's debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) .  Using these tools you can see JavaScript errors, AJAX requests, PHP (server) responses, individual page file loads etc etc.

Comment: Of course, I am already using Firebug with Firephp and make frequently use of debug_backtrace, but that shows only the stack trace of a certain function and not the complete workflow.

Comment: It might be difficult to get a complete snapshot of what's happening in something like a backtrace: PHP and JS logs will be in different places to start with.. you won't be able to see JavaScript things in a PHP backtrace.  Tools like Firebug/Chrome debugger are powerful tools to see what's happening in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of would be using Chrome developer tools, network tab in order to see the sequence of events. Or maybe even better, the HTTPFox plugin in firefox.
That will help you to find out the execution order of JS calls and which PHP files are accessed via AJAX.

What's happening on server side isn't easy to follow, but you could debug your code using [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/).